# draw lines from a set of coordinates pygame

Tags: python, list, drawing, pygame

I am using pygame to draw a set of lines on the screen I have the following code:

```
points = [list(map(int,elem.split())) if elem.strip().lower() != "j" else [-1, -1, -1] for elem in vlist]
```

this code will take my xyz coordinates and store them into a list in the following format:

```
[[-1,-1,-1],[366,-1722,583],[366,356,1783],[566,789,1033],[866,-1289,-167],[366,-1722,583],[-1,-1,-1],[-500,-1472,-600],[0,-1039,-600].....]
```

Each element that equals [-1,-1,-1] represents a point at which i need to stop drawing and move to the next point to continue drawing a new line.

So i need to draw the lines

```
[366,-1722,583],[366,356,1783],[566,789,1033],[866,-1289,-167],[366,-1722,583]
```

Then i need to stop drawing and move to a new point and start drawing from my new point

```
[-500,-1472,-600],[0,-1039,-600]
```

and continue reading like this until i get to the end of my sets of points

so how can i use pygame.draw.line to achieve this

Comment: Please note that Pygame is, by itself, a 2D framework.  So you will only be able to draw with the `x` and `y` coordinates of your points.  If you want to have a 3D application, I recommend looking into [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes i do know this i plan on switching to openGL later i just want to get the program working in pygame first with xy then change over to OpenGL.  Thank you for your input

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The draw the 2D components of the points, you can first generate the groups of lines you need to draw, and then use `pygame.draw.lines` to draw them:

```
from itertools import groupby

# Some itertools magic to split the list into groups with [-1,-1,-1] as the delimiter.
pointLists = [list(group) for k, group in groupby(points, lambda x: x == [-1,-1,-1]) if not k]
color = (255,255,255)
for pointList in pointLists:
    # Only use the x and y components of the points.
    drawPoints = [[l[0], l[1]] for l in pointList]
    # Assume 'screen' is your display surface.
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, color, False, drawPoints)
```

Comment: This seem like it should work but when i try and run it I get a SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment.  how would i fix this now to see if this code works?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the lambda expression was supposed to contain `==` instead of just `=`.  Answer is updated.

Comment: OK that fix works just one more question how can i multiply my x,y coordinate sets that I am drawing by a scale factor so they display on my screen

Comment: I would suggest finding the min and max `x` and `y` coordinates that you have, getting the range between them, and then mapping values on that range to the size of your window.  This would be a 'scale-to-fit' operation.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
lines = []

for point in points:
    if point == (-1,-1,-1):
        pygame.draw.lines(Surface, color, closed, lines, width=1)
        lines = []
        continue

    lines.append(point)
```